# Unable to import module from another folder

Tags: python

my file directory is as follows

```
mein_paket
--src
----__init__.py
----script.py
--tests
----test.py
```

In my `tests/test.py` file, I have the following code:

```
from mein_paket.src.script import Cat

c = Cat('aicri')
c.meow()
```

However I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mein_paket'`

I have tried different importing methods such as

```
from mein_paket.src.script import Cat
from mein_paket.src import Cat
from src.script import Cat
from src import Cat
```

But none seem to work, I'm also trying to avoid the use of `sys.append`.

Comment: working in pychram??

Comment: I'm not using PyCharm, I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: try to go into setting<variable and then choose system like windows go to title as per your requirement  i guess you need to add ${rootPath}  in that

Comment: If other people run my script, they will also need to add the variable in their system?

Comment: no its not like that if it is not included may be it could led to same error! btw have you tried it??

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Your import statement should be `from src.script import Cat`, which I see you have tried, but you have to run the code from the `mein_paket` directory like this: `python -m tests.test`